# How we can use the function of another schema's package in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a function in package and I want to access that function in another schema.
I have already given the execution rights of package to another schema however I am not able to use that package's function.

```
Package PKG_Test  is FUNCTION FUN_TESTING(x IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2; End;
```

Now i want to access the `FUN_TESING` in another schema.

Comment: Ok. Show us what you've tried. What's the error you get? Please provide more details. SO is not a guessing site.

Comment: I am getting the  error ORA-00904:---------- 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51150770/edit) to show the package and function definition, the grants you did, the code you are attempting to run and the error you get from that - all as formatted text (not images).

Comment: You still haven't shown the grants or how you are calling it when you get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting the error
>
> ```
> ORA-00904:---------- 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause: *Action: –
> ```

You need to grant permission for the other user to execute the package:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PKG_test TO other_user;
```

Then the `OTHER_USER` can call it by prefixing the function name with the schema name and the package name:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( OWNING_USER.PKG_TEST.FUN_TESTING( 1 ) );
END;
/
```